# Android Error Cant Use FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE here

Tags: android

I am trying to start AppB from AppA.   On activity of AppB I issue:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
             i.setAction("START_APPB");
             i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                             context.sendBroadcast(i)
```

Inside AppB I have a broadcast receiver that is listening on START_APPB intent filter.

as follows:

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setAction("SHOW_APPBPAGE");
        context.startActivity(i);
```

Note in each case context is the activities context of the respective app.

This causes a crash error from activity manager:

```
IllegalArgumentException:  Can't use FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE here
```

I have never seen this error before. When i have sent same message from first activity of App it runs without error, but somehow not on 3rd page , using context of third page.

Comment: Please note I have not directly used FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE anywhere.

Comment: I have another way of starting the second app now, namely just staring the activity of the app instead of sending it a broadcast, this works without error but for some reason broadcast receiver to broadcast receiver in another app is not working, and it would be good to know what the source of this error is and where it comes from.

Comment: Why mark down a question that has a rare error in it.  That makes no sense.  Just be glad I posted it so someone can reproduce and maybe get answers.  I have another way to solve the same problem so I did not post this just to solve my issue.

Answer (score 11):

Do not use any `FLAG_ACTIVITY_` constant with `sendBroadcast()`.

Comment: I think I got an error without FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK but then when I added NEWTASK on both sides, I got the error above.

Comment: Android error suggested I needed FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and then I got error.  I have not seen this before.  It seems to have to do with issuing the broadcast from activity somewhere in stack.  When I use main activity I did not see this error.

Comment: And its the ActivityManager that does not like this for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

When populating your Intent, do:

```
intent.setFlags(0);
```

Comment: If you got here from apps-for-android's AnyCut app like I did. This is the correct answer, just add `result.setFlags(0)` to just before the `sendBroadcast(result)` in `FrontDoorActivity.java:onActivityResult()`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this and found out that this is a bug in android. At some point in history this two flags - `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE` - get the same numeric value because some android developer changed one of their values without checking that it is already taken by another flag. The latest version (4.4) seems to have it fixed already.