# Getting 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't use FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE here' in device running android 2.3.3

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have an activity which lets user to schedule an event by choosing the date and time.I have done it using the AlarmManager

```
Intent i=new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
i.putExtra("status",status);
i.putExtra("mode",mode);
PendingIntent p=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sched_time, p);
```

In the broadcast receiver a new Activity is launched

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent data) {
    // Start the scheduled post
    String status=data.getExtras().getString("status");
    int mode=data.getExtras().getInt("mode");

    Intent i=new Intent(context,PostScheduled.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("status", status);
    i.putExtra("mode", mode);

    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

In the emulator this code runs fine but in actual device(running android 2.3.3) it crashes at the line

```
PendingIntent p=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Here's the Stack trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't use FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE here
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1326)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:2254)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:230)
at com.social.autofunnystatus.ScheduleDialog.onClick(ScheduleDialog.java:158)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone has any clue what's going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438681/android-error-cant-use-flag-receiver-boot-upgrade-here

Comment: @jellyfication that thread doesn't answer anything :( and I have one additional problem,the app isn't crashing on emulator(also running 2.3.3).

Comment: What are passing as the `i` parameter when you're calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast(..)`? Consider adding the definition of this `Intent` to your question.

Comment: @Jens added the definition..AlarmReceiver is the broadcast receiver class.

Comment: insted of this  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT you use PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE` flag is a "decoration" tacked on by the `ActivityManagerService` when you specifically define the broadcast target like you do here:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
```

If you were to define an action, e.g. "`com.whateveryour.package.is.ACTION_ALARM`" and declare the `AlarmReceiver` in a `<receiver />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` - and then create the `Intent` like this:

```
Intent i=new Intent("com.whateveryour.package.is.ACTION_ALARM");
i.putExtra("status",status);
i.putExtra("mode",mode);
PendingIntent p=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

you'd get rid of that pesky flag that's blocking you.

Comment: I just want to launch a new activity from the broadcast receiver. and I've defined the receiver in manifest like this:
    `<receiver
      android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
    </receiver>`
do i need to change anything else than just creating the Intent as u suggested?

Comment: You would need to add an <`intent-filter`> for whatever you pick as the broadcast intent action. Just defining a `<receiver>` without `android:exported="true"` or an `<intent-filter>` only makes it available for "in-application" use - and the alarm manager & pending intents are external.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug in android. At some point in history this two flags - `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_RECEIVER_BOOT_UPGRADE` - get the same numeric value because some android developer changed one of their values without checking that it is already taken by another flag. The latest version (4.4) seems to have it fixed already.